# Unix sort treatment of underscore character

Tags: sorting, unix, environment-variables, collation

I have two linux machines, on which unix sort seems to behave differently. I believe I've narrowed it down to the treatment of the underscore character.

If I run `sort tmp`, where tmp contains the following two lines:

```
aa_d_hh
aa_dh_ey
```

one machine outputs

```
aa_d_hh
aa_dh_ey
```

(i.e. '_' precedes 'h') while the other outputs

```
aa_dh_ey
aa_d_hh
```

(i.e. 'h' precedes '_'). I need these machines to behave together (as I use sort -m later, to merge very large files).

Is there any way I can force sort to behave in one way or the other?

Thanks.

Comment: try sort --version on both machines .. are they same??

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can set `LC_COLLATE` to traditional sort order just for your command:

```
env LC_COLLATE=C sort tmp
```

This won't change the current environment just the one in which the sort command executes.
You should have the same behaviour with this.

Comment: What are some other valid choices of LC_COLLATE?  Suppose I specifically want to move underscores bottom?  What value would do that?

Comment: `LC_COLLATE=en_US.ASCII` is another valid choice, which has the same sort order for underscores as `C`.

Answer (score 8):

This is likely caused by a difference in locale. In the `en_US.UTF-8` locale, underscores (`_`) sort after letters and numbers, whereas in the [POSIX `C` locale](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87748/58453) they sort after uppercase letters and numbers, but *before* lowercase letters.

```sh
# won't change LC_COLLATE=C after execution
$ LC_COLLATE=C sort filename
```

You can also use `sort --debug` to show more information about the sorting behavior in general:

```
$ (echo 'foo_bar'; echo 'fooAbar'; echo 'foo0bar'; echo 'fooabar') |
      LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8 sort --debug
sort: using ‘en_US.UTF-8’ sorting rules
foo0bar
fooabar
fooAbar
foo_bar

$ (echo 'foo_bar'; echo 'fooAbar'; echo 'foo0bar'; echo 'fooabar') | 
      LC_COLLATE=C sort --debug
sort: using simple byte comparison
foo0bar
fooAbar
foo_bar
fooabar
```

As also shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1184338/20789), you can use the above formula to force `LC_COLLATE=C` for a single command, without modifying your shell environment:

Answer (score 4):

sort order depends on the current value of the environment variable LC_COLLATE.  Check your local documentation for 'locale', 'setlocale', etc.  Set LC_COLLATE to 'POSIX' on both machines, and the results should match.

Comment: there is no such environment variable on my machine, yet sort works fine.

Answer (score 4):

I really liked the answer above with the useful example, i'd just add another string to its list to show how strange the sorting behavior can be:

```
$ (echo 'foo_bar'; echo 'fooAbar'; echo 'foo0bar'; echo 'fooabar'; echo 'foobbar'; echo 'foobar') | LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8 sort --debug
sort: using ‘en_US.UTF-8’ sorting rules
foo0bar
_______
fooabar
_______
fooAbar
_______
foobar
______
foo_bar
_______
foobbar
_______
```

Seems crazy right ? 
Found the explanation here, in this case it's because the unicode collation algorithm is being used in this locale : 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252419/unexpected-sort-order-in-en-us-utf-8-locale

HOWEVER, even the '**sort --debug**' option is not able to easily demonstrate the subtleties that go into the **strcoll**() function's rules for obeying the locale sorting specification.

POSIX stipulates that locale authors (for all but the C locale) have absolute control over all sorts of fiddly aspects of how **strcoll**() behaves, and the fact that two vendors declare that their locale is *named* **en_US.UTF-8** does ***NOT*** imply/*require* those two vendors to have the same locale definition. 
So the collation rules between two different platforms are very likely different, based on whoever wrote the locale file for that platform, and what bug fixes have been incorporated into the locale definition over time.

Thank you Eric Blake at Red Hat for this insight.

Comment: Use `sort -V` solved my problem. As `sort --help` says: `-V, --version-sort          natural sort of (version) numbers within text`, it deal with underscore and put it to the end.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is due to your [**locale**](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/guide-localization.xml#doc_chap3).  Use the [`locale`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man1/locale.1.html) command to check the current settings.

There are a number of different locale categories, such as `LC_COLLATE`, `LC_TIME`, and `LC_MESSAGES`.  You can change them all by setting the environment variable `LC_ALL` or `LANG`, or only the collation (sort) order by setting the environment variable `LC_COLLATE`.  The locale `C` or `POSIX` is a basic locale defined by the standard; others include `en_US` (US English), `fr_FR` (French), etc.