# Linux and OSX and Android sorting according to a locale not consistent

Tags: java, android, bash, sorting

I and trying to get the same sorting order for Android and Linux and OSX.
I am comparing the sort command results of Linux and OSX compared to
so custom code on android that operate on a similar file set.

On Linux / OSX I use this command:

```
find {folder_name} -type f | sort
```

and in java / android I am using this - but the sorting orders
do not align:

```
 private Enumeration<InputStream> getSortedStreams(HashMap<String,InputStream> collection) {

    Vector<InputStream> fileSreams = new Vector<>();

    List<String> keys = new ArrayList(collection.keySet());

    Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.US);//<<???
    Collections.sort(keys,collator);
    for (String key: keys) {
        Log.d(TAG, "getSortedStreams: " + key);
        fileSreams.add(collection.get(key));
    }

    return fileSreams.elements();
}
```

Android output:

```
1000/abc_d.txt
1000/abc-d.txt
```

OSX output:

```
1000/abc-d.txt
1000/abc_d.txt
```

I am assuming the differences are because of the locales used
to sort the file list. From what I gather OSX and Linux are both
POSIX compliant although Linux is not certified. Android is also not POSIX compliant but my guess it is fine with regards to sorting.

I have details below trying to make sense and to get a consistent
experience across the platforms.

It seems that I can control both Linux and Android to align, but OSX is ignoring the environment variables I set.

I need specific help to set the locales so that I get a consistent results
across the platforms.

I have not done tests on IOS yet, if required I can submit them.

**More details:**

On Fedora Core.

Test case:
create two files with the following names in a directory named sort_test

```
sort_test/abc_d.txt
sort_test/abc-d.txt
```

**On Fedora Linux Core 17 - 3.9.10-100.fc17.x86_64**

locale -a for en_US is:

```
locale -a | grep en_US

en_US
en_US.iso88591
en_US.iso885915
en_US.utf8
```

**USING C**

```
find sort_test/ -type f | env -i LC_COLLATE=C sort
sort_test/abc-d.txt
sort_test/abc_d.txt
```

**USING en_US.utf8**

```
find sort_test/ -type f | env -i LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8 sort
sort_test/abc_d.txt
sort_test/abc-d.txt
```

**On OSX - seems to messed up, setting the locale has no effect:**

local -a gives a list of locales, and the en_US locales are:

```
en_US
en_US.ISO8859-1
en_US.ISO8859-15
en_US.US-ASCII
en_US.UTF-8
```

**USING C**

```
  find sort_test -type f | env -i LC_COLLATE=C sort
    sort_test/abc-d.txt
    sort_test/abc_d.txt
```

**USING en_US.UTF-8**

```
find sort_test -type f | env -i LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8 sort
sort_test/abc-d.txt
sort_test/abc_d.txt
```

**On Android I set the locale to use a POSIX locale:**

```
  Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US", "POSIX");<<< the fix
    Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(locale);
    Collections.sort(keys,collator);
    for (String key: keys) {
        Log.d(TAG, "getSortedStreams: " + key);
        fileStreams.add(collection.get(key));
    }


    /1000/abc-d.txt
    /1000/abc_d.txt
```

**On Android I set the locale to US:**

```
//Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US", "POSIX");
Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.US);
Collections.sort(keys,collator);
for (String key: keys) {
    Log.d(TAG, "getSortedStreams: " + key);
    fileStreams.add(collection.get(key));
}

/1000/abc_d.txt
/1000/abc-d.txt
```

**LINUX locale variables are: locale command output:**

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

**OSX locale variables are: locale command output:**

```
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: They both should do alphabetical ordering. Can you give the output they both produce?

Comment: Also, maybe you should sort `fileSreams` before you return it instead of `keys`. There is no reason to sort `keys` because you just get out the value from the HashMap in the original order

Comment: I have updated the question with some outputs.

Seems like Android and Bash are not treating _ and - the same.

Comment: As I said in the second comment, I don't think you're really sorting anything before you add to the Vector. HashMap ordering is not guaranteed, so no matter what order the keys are in, it's the values that you really care about

Comment: I read the code as follows: I pass in a collection of strings aka file names and the actual file content.

Then I sort the collection according to the file names - and then retrieve then retrieve the corresponding file contents and add to the initially empty fileStreams collection in a sorted order.

Comment: I have just confirmed that OSX and Linux do not sort the same
way - probably why Android is not sorting as the OSX bash command.
Linux puts the underscore first.

Comment: I have noticed this question that relates but still nothing seems to work for me yet.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184268/unix-sort-treatment-of-underscore-character

Answer (score 2):

The solution that seems to work for me currently is to align all the operating systems with OSX.

**Linux:**

```
find sort_test -type f | env -i LC_COLLATE=C sort
```

**OSX:**

```
find sort_test -type f | env -i LC_COLLATE=C sort
```

**Android:**

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US", "POSIX");<<< the fix
Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(locale);
Collections.sort(keys,collator);
```