# Sorting with underscore in Lua Redis

Tags: sorting, lua, redis, locale

I have a problem with tables being sorted in a different ways on my two ubuntu servers. I'm executing the following command in the redis-cli tool. This is the server 1:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> eval "local a = {'_mcat:banner','for_meta:1','_size:300x250','_mtype:html', 'axx:1'};table.sort(a);return a;" 0
1) "_mcat:banner"
2) "_mtype:html"
3) "_size:300x250"
4) "axx:1"
5) "for_meta:1"
```

And the server 2:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> eval "local a = {'_mcat:banner','for_meta:1','_size:300x250','_mtype:html', 'axx:1'};table.sort(a);return a;" 0
1) "axx:1"
2) "for_meta:1"
3) "_mcat:banner"
4) "_mtype:html"
5) "_size:300x250"
```

As you can see the problem lays in how the sort is treating the '_' character. I have tried to upgrade versions of redis & gcc and the behavior is not changed between the servers. Redis versions tested: 2.8.4, 2.8.19, 4.0.2, gcc version: 4.8.2. Running *locale* returns the same values on both servers:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Executing the same code in Python, works the same on both machines:

```
>>> sorted(['_mcat:banner','for_meta:1','_size:300x250','_mtype:html', 'axx:1'])
['_mcat:banner', '_mtype:html', '_size:300x250', 'axx:1', 'for_meta:1']
```

Maybe somebody has a suggestion on what to try next? Thanks.

**EDITED**:

On both servers running:

```
eval "local a = {'_mcat:banner','for_meta:1','_size:300x250','_mtype:html', 'axxx:2'};table.sort(a, function(a,b) return a<b end);return a;" 0
```

Produces results consistent with the table.sort(a) (so different between servers), but take a look at this:

On server 1:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> eval "local a;if 'axxx:2'>'_mcat:banner' then a=1 else a=0 end;return a;" 0
(integer) 1

127.0.0.1:6379> eval "local a;if 'a'>'_' then a=1 else a=0 end;return a;" 0
(integer) 1
```

On server 2:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> eval "local a;if 'axxx:2'>'_mcat:banner' then a=1 else a=0 end;return a;" 0
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> eval "local a;if 'a'>'_' then a=1 else a=0 end;return a;" 0
(integer) 1
```

Comment: Weird - looking at the embedded Lua engine in Redis I don't see how that's possible

Comment: Weird indeed; maybe try `print('a'>'_', 'ax'>'_m', 'axx'>'_mc', 'axxx'>'_mca')` and so on to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: @Paul Kulchenko 'ax' > '_m' returns 0 and it's 0 onwards. Do you have any suggestions on what can I do with this information?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is that you are not using the actual underscore, but rather some unicode variant of it that has multi-byte content such that the first byte value is smaller than 'a', but the second byte value is larger than lower-case characters, which would produce the result you see. If it's not that, then maybe @ItamarHaber can suggest something...

Comment: on both servers run `eval "return string.byte('_', 1, string.len('_'))"`

Comment: `print('a'>'_', 'ax'>'_m', 'axx'>'_mc', 'axxx'>'_mca')` should return `true` four times, never 0 or 1.

Comment: Can't reproduce the 0 and in terms of locale, things are pretty much hardcoded to follow the OS if at all. I wonder what would happen if the same code was run using a standalone Lua interpreter on both servers... Anyway, IMO think server 2 has gone south and should be restrapped ;P

Comment: @AlexanderAltshuler `eval "return string.byte('_', 1, string.len('_'))"` returns 95 on both servers. @ItamarHaber yeah, I'll give it till the end of the week and I'll probably rebuild the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments and suggestions, I still don't know what exactly happened but rebuilding the server worked.

Answer (score 3):

Given that `table.sort` is implemented in Lua itself using quicksort (`src/ltablib.c`) and for strings the comparison boils down to `strcoll` call, it's difficult to say where it could go wrong for underscores. I would try adding a custom sort function to see if this changes the outcome (`table.sort(a, function(a,b) return a<b end)`) and if it still produces the incorrect results, then you can print `a, b, a<b` values to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've tried a few more things, take a look at the edited question

Comment: It seems that locale can change sort order even for underscores, so it may have been that. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43081689/5751627 for an example.