# How to make sort consider "_" in Bash?

Tags: bash, sorting

I have a list of folders

```bash
$ ls -1 . 
_dns
linux
mariadb
minio
mongodb
nginx
_postgresdb
_python
_rabbitmq
redis
sphinx
supervisor
$
```

I would like to have them in the lexicographic order (the order provide by e.g. the vim sort):

```bash
$
_dns
_postgresdb
_python
_rabbitmq
linux
mariadb
minio
mongodb
nginx
redis
sphinx
supervisor
$
```

I don't succeed to do that with the unix sort:

```bash
$ ls -1 . | sort
_dns
linux
mariadb
minio
mongodb
nginx
_postgresdb
_python
_rabbitmq
redis
sphinx
supervisor
$
```

even with options:

```bash
$ ls -1 . | sort  -g
_dns
linux
mariadb
minio
mongodb
nginx
_postgresdb
_python
_rabbitmq
redis
sphinx
supervisor
$

$ ls -1 . | sort  -b
_dns
linux
mariadb
minio
mongodb
nginx
_postgresdb
_python
_rabbitmq
redis
sphinx
supervisor
$

$ ls -1 . | sort  -n
_dns
linux
mariadb
minio
mongodb
nginx
_postgresdb
_python
_rabbitmq
redis
sphinx
supervisor
$
```

Note: this question as been answered in a much better way in [Unix sort treatment of underscore character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184268/unix-sort-treatment-of-underscore-character)

Comment: Can't reproduce this on OS X.

Comment: It works perfectly on OS X.

Comment: Whaat happens if you do `$ sort <(ls -1 .)`? Or `$ ls -1 . >file` then `$ sort file`?

Comment: This is indeed reproducible on linux. The question actually is about GNU `sort`.

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a persistent solution you can export `LC_COLLATE`

```bash
$ ls -1  | sort

_dns
linux
mariadb
minio
mongodb
nginx
_postgresdb
_python
_rabbitmq
redis
sphinx
supervisor
```

```bash
$ export LC_COLLATE=C
$ ls -1  | sort

_dns
_postgresdb
_python
_rabbitmq
linux
mariadb
minio
mongodb
nginx
redis
sphinx
supervisor
```

Answer (score 3):

As [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43081689/1328439) suggests, the issue is in the locale settings.

Use POSIX C locale to get the result you expect.

```
$ cat tmp/filelist.txt  | LC_COLLATE=C /usr/bin/sort
_dns
_postgresdb
_python
_rabbitmq
linux
mariadb
minio
mongodb
nginx
redis
sphinx
supervisor
```

While with `en_US.utf8` locale you would get what you are getting now.

```
$ cat tmp/filelist.txt  | LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8 /usr/bin/sort 
_dns
linux
mariadb
minio
mongodb
nginx
_postgresdb
_python
_rabbitmq
redis
sphinx
supervisor
```

*Note that this answer is based on `sort` from GNU coreutils version 8.32.*