# File sorting in R differs across the VMs (issue with underscores)

Tags: r, linux, sorting

I have 2 virtual machines that have the same LC_COLLATE env var value: en_US.UTF-8. On one machine I have files sorted with underscore strings starting first (which I accept as desired sorting) and on the second I have strings that start from underscore listed somewhere in the middle

```
list.files('dir', recursive=TRUE)
```

which sorts in the following way on the first machine (this is the desired sorting):

```
_example/abc.R
01_example/123.R
02_example/def.R
site.R
tab.R
```

On the other machine I have the following order:

```
01_example/123.R
02_example/def.R
_example/abc.R
site.R
tab.R
```

It is worth mentioning that I have tried to set up LC_COLLATE=C and still have not got underscore lines first. Environment variables have been set system-wide and in R using Sys.setlocale().

The question is: What should I do to achieve correct sorting (underscore strings first)?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You want the locale to be `"C.UTF8"`. Locale [`"C"`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39827/how-do-i-make-ls-sort-underscore-characters-first),

> takes characters in their numerical order. `_` falls between uppercase and lowercase

Using your example:

```r
# Create some files
dirs <- c("_example", "01_example", "02_example")
files <- c("_example/abc.R", "01_example/123.R", "02_example/def.R", "site.R", "tab.R")
lapply(dirs, dir.create)
lapply(files, file.create)

# Locale C
Sys.setlocale(
    "LC_COLLATE", "C"
)
list.files()
# [1] "01_example" "02_example" "_example"   "site.R"     "tab.R"

# Locale C.UTF8
Sys.setlocale(
    "LC_COLLATE", "C.UTF8"
)
list.files()
# [1] "_example"   "01_example" "02_example" "site.R"     "tab.R"
```

See also [Unix sort treatment of underscore character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184268/unix-sort-treatment-of-underscore-character) and  [PostgreSQL: difference between collations 'C' and 'C.UTF-8'](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/240930/postgresql-difference-between-collations-c-and-c-utf-8) on DBA Stack Exchange.

Comment: thank you for the fast response, but I am getting the same order no matter if the locale is C or C.UTF8 :(

Comment: @Shoakhmad that is odd - I can't replicate it so not sure how to fix it. I suspect you may find yourself copying `iso14651_t1` and tweaking the rules as [here](https://svmiller.com/blog/2019/07/notes-to-self-new-linux-installation-r-ubuntu/#bettersort). I'd be a bit wary of that though and probably just do `stringr::str_sort(list.files(), numeric=TRUE)`.

Comment: Of course these files are just examples, but with changing locale from en_US.UTF-8 to C.UTF8, underscored files (let's say _example/abc.R, _example/bbc.R, _example/cbc.R, _example/dbc.R, _example/ebc.R)  with en_US.UTF-8 are in order range 83-87 and for C.UTF-8 they are at 50-54 range. The range here is the index number, when I print the variable which stores the paths to files